# ¿Como poner la primera letra del mes en mayusculas en datetimepicker winforms c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Alguien sabe la forma para poner en mayúscula la primera letra del mes ejemplo Enero, Febrero, Marzo etc.., ya que con este código lo pone pero en minúsculas:

```
        public void SetMyCustomFormat()
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM-yyyy";
    }
```

y el resultado es el siguiente, en donde puedo cambiar los meses y los años:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si agrego el siguiente código lo convierte, pero ya no me deja cambiar nada del datetimepicker:

```
        public void SetMyCustomFormat()
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM-yyyy";
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = char.ToUpper(dateTimePicker1.Text[0]) + dateTimePicker1.Text.Substring(1);
    }
```

El resultado es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

@Gustavo Jose en C# existe una funcion que si coges un string te pone la primera letra en mayuscula. La funcion es la siguiente.

```
string texto = "hola, gustavo jose"
string result = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(texto);
```

El resultado seria el siguiente: **Hola, gustavo jose**

Comment: si lo intenté de esta forma antes, pero el resultado es el mismo, si convierte a mayúscula la primera letra pero ya no me permite cambiar el mes y el año, en otras palabras me inhabilita el control datetimepicker.